# Add Variable to Livewire Navigation Menu

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to **add a variable($countTeacherDuplicates) which contains a count of an array** **beside the navigation link title**. I have already registered the variable as a global array in the AppServiceProviders. I just couldn't quite get how the syntax works

**Tried this so far but totally getting syntax error**

```
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('join-teach') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('join-teach')">
                    {{ __('Instructor Conflicts','('$countTeacherDuplicates')') }}
                </x-jet-nav-link>
            </div>
```

**Can anyone help me this is the last piece for my project**.Thanks to whoever responds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Missing concat operator between your string and variable,  `'('$` should be `'('.$`. And the same on the other side

Comment: And why do you register it in the service provider? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
 <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('join-teach') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('join-teach')">
  {{ __("Instructor Conflicts {$countTeacherDuplicates}") }}
 </x-jet-nav-link>
</div>
```

```
Output: Instructor Conflicts 1
```

also

```
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
 <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('join-teach') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('join-teach')">
  {{ __('Instructor Conflicts' . "('$countTeacherDuplicates')") }}
 </x-jet-nav-link>
</div>
```

```
Output: Instructor Conflicts('1')
```

Note: You used `,` "comma". For translation e.g `{{text}}`, `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php`'s `get` method is used to called. So pass correct parameters.

```php
public function get($key, array $replace = [], $locale = null, $fallback = true)
```

NB: On the other hand `.` "dot" is a string concatenator.